# Mat-tab-group angular component tab toggling tab on its own

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-tab

I have a user report that when they constantly switch between tabs while data is still being loading (separate API calls per tab) the tabs will start switching on it own and the user must refresh the page to regain control.

https://streamable.com/nu5l2s

I tried disabling animations but the issue still persists. I tried disabling/delay tab switching until each tab finish loading data but I want to know if there is a better way while still allowing users to switch between tabs.

here's a snippet of code with one tab. Each tab has the same logic

```
<mat-tab-group [@.disabled]="StopTabSwitchingAnimation" color="accent" class="demo-tab-group" [selectedIndex]="TabStateHelper.ConversationsListTabSelectedIndex" (selectedTabChange)="tabChanged($event)">
  <mat-tab>
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
      Active &nbsp;<span *ngIf="TotalActiveConversationCount" class="tab-message-count">{{TotalActiveConversationCount}}</span>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template matTabContent>
        <div class="demo-tab-content" infiniteScroll [infiniteScrollDistance]="0.7" [infiniteScrollThrottle]="100" (scrolled)="onScrollDown()"
                [scrollWindow]="false">
            <app-all-conversations [Conversations]="Conversations"></app-all-conversations>
            <div *ngIf="LoadingActiveConversations" class="loading-conversations">
                <mat-sourcing-spinner [IsSpinnerActive]="LoadingActiveConversations" [IsLoadingList]="true"></mat-sourcing-spinner>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>

....

</mat-tab-group>
```

```
constructor(private _conversationService: ConversationService,
    private _authService: AuthenticationService) {
    this.TabStateHelper = TabStateHelper.Instance;
  }

public tabChanged(event: MatTabChangeEvent): void {
    this.TabStateHelper.ConversationsListTabSelectedIndex = event.index;
  }
```

Comment: Could you provide the code you use?

Comment: @orlyohreally added html

Comment: Do you use subjects/behavior subjects/etc. by any chance? I had issue in my code when dialog would appear by no apparent reason, but it turned out that I didn't unsubscribe from observable (behaviour subject) which triggered the dialog.

Comment: I do in a couple places