# Angular mat-tab forming tab toggling on its own when selected fast

Tags: angular, typescript

Having an issue using angular material's mat-tab, where if tabs are toggled really fast it starts toggling between tabs infinitely, along with the content of the tab.

> the ts file

```
    tabChanged = (tabChangeEvent: MatTabChangeEvent): void => {
            this.selectedTabIndex = tabChangeEvent.index;
            this.toggleColorTab1 = "accent"
            this.toggleColorTab2 = "accent"
            this.Table1 = false;
            this.Table2 = false;
            if (this.selectedTabIndex == 0) {
                this.toggleColorTab1 = "primary"
                this.Table1 = true;
                //table1 api-call
            } else if (this.selectedTabIndex == 1) {
                this.toggleColorTab2 = "primary"
                this.Table2 = true;
                //table2 api-call
            }
        }
```

> the html file

```
<mat-tab-group [(selectedIndex)]="selectedTabIndex"
                           (selectedTabChange)="tabChanged($event)">
              <mat-tab label="Tab 1"
                       [aria-label]="toggleColorTab1">
              </mat-tab>
              <mat-tab label="Tab 2"
                       [aria-label]="toggleColorTab2">
              </mat-tab>
            </mat-tab-group>
```

- Example: happens when I select tab1 then tab2 then swap back really fast back to tab1 then tab2 repeatedly then the tabs as well as the content keeps toggling unless I refresh the page or log-out*
  **P.S: i think its similar to this question asked ,but this problem still occurs whether or not i use an api call on any tab selection**
  [Mat-tab-group angular component tab toggling tab on its own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62029833/mat-tab-group-angular-component-tab-toggling-tab-on-its-own)